# QPlainTextEdit highlight current line with soft wraps？

Tags: python, pyqt

This snippet can only highlight current line, but it cannot highlight line with soft wraps.

[image: screenshot]

```py
    def highlightCurrentLine(self):
        extraSelections = []
        if not self.isReadOnly() and self.toPlainText():   # and self.toPlainText()
            selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
            lineColor = QColor(Qt.yellow).lighter(160)
            selection.format.setBackground(lineColor)
            selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat.FullWidthSelection, True)
            selection.cursor = self.textCursor()
            selection.cursor.clearSelection()
            extraSelections.append(selection)
        self.setExtraSelections(extraSelections)
```

Comment: Why are you using `QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()` instead of [`extraSelections()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#extraSelections)? Also, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante I just reuse other people's code. `QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()` will exit with -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: Then those people are wrong, or you didn't use their code properly. We still need a proper MRE, though.